# How to store a particular value and retrieve the concatenation in Lua?

Tags: lua

I have four functions.
each function executing time.
it will store some different value in the table.
when Enter function is executed then it retrieves.
one by one.
whatever functions data stored in the table.

```
table={} 
function one()
    table.one="1"
end 
function two()
    table.two="2"
end 
function three() 
    table.three="3"
end 
function four() 
    table.four="4" 
end
function enter() 
    for i,v in pairs(table)do 
        print("on by one",v)
    end
end 
one() 
two() 
enter()
```

output: `1 2` (it is sequence one by one)
I want output like this: `12`
if I next time execute function different order time then

```
two()
one()
enter()
```

output: `2 1` (it is sequence one by one)
I want output like this: `21`
if i next time execute

```
two() 
three()
four()
enter()
```

I want output like this `234`
is this possible to write code.
please help anyone

Comment: Please format the question/code properly

Comment: Question is more confusing please edit you question and mention your issue clearly

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not a good idea to overwrite `table`.

If you are interested in getting your table elements in a particular order you should not use the `pairs` iterator as it makes use of `next` which enumerates table keys in an unspecified order.

```
local digits = {}
function one()
  table.insert(digits, 1)
end
function enter()
  print(table.concat(digits))
  digits = {}
end
```

Note that this will only work for string or number values.